# Frobenius reciprocities

Tags: ct.category-theory, soft-question, quantum-groups

An adjunction of the form $\mathrm{Hom}(A \otimes X, Y) \cong \mathrm{Hom}(X, A^* \otimes Y)$ in a rigid monoidal category is sometimes called Frobenius reciprocity. Is there a result that unifies this adjunction with the familiar adjunction between the induction and the restriction of representations? What explains this coincidence in terminology?

Comment: Frobenius reciprocity is a tensor-hom adjunction: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor-hom_adjunction